# Is it possible to extract contents of a *non* self-extracting .exe file?

Tags: windows, macos, extract, exe

Well.... the question sort of says it all. If possible I would like to be able to do so from a Linux or macOS environment, but I have virtualized Windows if need be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you want to extract files/installer data and not icons/images from the .exe installer?

Answer (score 2):

There is no general answer for this because different installers/applications use different storage methods. You should first try to identify the author of the installer software by looking for clues in the version information and maybe with a hex editor.

My first suggestion is to try [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), it can extract from NSIS based installers and some MSI based installers.

If the setup was created with Inno Setup then you can try [this](http://innounp.sourceforge.net/).

If all else fails, try [Universal Extractor](https://www.legroom.net/software/uniextract) but even that will fail for obscure and custom .exe files.

Answer (score -1):

It depends. Assuming you have a PE file (windows executable), you can use a resource editor https://stefansundin.github.io/xn_resource_editor/ to extract icons, messages or dialog layouts. This assumes that the author of that file used the native resource system. Other data would only be available if you knew the address within the PE file, or had appropriate debug symbols. But then, you must guess content type, and maybe also file size.

Comment: Oh wow there's a lot more that goes into it than I thought... Basically I have a bios file downloaded from the manufacturer's website that's in a .exe format, I'm trying to just extract the files I need and manually flash the chip instead of "automating" the process.

Comment: So your problem is that you need to flash your BIOS but cannot do so because you need to run the windows executable to do so. If so, there can be more details on how you should proceed on the mobo manufactures website.