# Is it possible to edit python file that was recently converted to an exe file

Tags: python

I just converted a python file to an exe file, but I realized I made a mistake on the Python file, is there a way to still edit the exe file without having to make a completely new exe file?

Comment: No there isn't, it's a [binary file][1] 

Is it so much work to create a new .exe ?

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file

Answer (score 0):

It might not be possible but it highly depends on how your used converter handles the python code and in which [format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe) the `.exe` was created.

A question about [Extracting the content of an EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943071/is-it-possible-to-extract-contents-of-a-non-self-extracting-exe-file) is here.

You might wanna (mentioned in the question above) try to unzip the ´exe` and extract it's contents. You could also try to check if your python code is handled as an asset with [XN Resource Editor](https://stefansundin.github.io/xn_resource_editor/)
, though I personally have not tried it.